# How does JavaScript exactly flow?

Tags: javascript

```js
const defaultResult = 0;
let currentResult = defaultResult;
currentResult = currentResult + 10**3;

let calculateDescription= `(+ ${defaultResult} + +10**3 )`;

outputResult(currentResult, calculateDescription);

function add(num1 ,num2)
{
    const result= num1 + num2;
    return result;    
}

currentResult = add(3,12);
```

Now what I gather is the answer should be 15 `add(3,12)` but it is coming `1000(10**3)`. Any idea why?

Comment: With very few exceptions, JavaScript is basically run line by line. `outputResult(...)` is called before `currentResult` is updated, so...

Comment: I am not aware of a language that will execute calculations and assignments from *further down the code* earlier and as a result replace the current value of a variable.

Comment: [MDN Order of Operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because the currentResult is being set in `currentResult=currentResult + 10**3;`

If you change the currenResult in `currentResult= add(3,12);` for another variable it will work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I got the answer now 
outputResult(...) is called before currentResult is updated so it is rendering that . If i put it after the currentResult or in the end i am getting the expected answer

Answer (score 0):

After this block

```
currentResult=currentResult + 10**3;

let calculateDescription= `(+ ${defaultResult} + +10**3 )`

outputResult(currentResult, calculateDescription);
```

nothing else matters - you never call `outputResult()` again, so there won't be any other answer coming, no matter what you set `currentResult` to. If you want the answer to come after you've set `currentResult` to a new value, you need to add more code to the end:

```
function add(num1 ,num2)
{
    const result= num1 + num2;
    return result;    
}

currentResult = add(3,12);

calculateDescription= `(+ ${defaultResult} + add(3,12) )`

outputResult(currentResult, calculateDescription);
```

Comment: I have called the outputResult() in index.html in other file

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, you could read this [How JavaScript Works](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-javascript-works-1706b9b66c4d) and this [JS: Execution of Synchronous and Asynchronous codes](https://medium.com/@siddharthac6/javascript-execution-of-synchronous-and-asynchronous-codes-40f3a199e687).

About the current problem, it's a little hard cuz this's just a snippet of your code. So, what `outputResult` it's suppose to do?

Your `add` function it's working as expected.